# Loop through and print and sum columns linux

Tags: linux, loops, gzip

I want to go through 22 data sets labeled the same by chr1- chr22. This is what one file looks like. als.sumstats.meta.chr10.txt.gz. I want to unzip these files and extract all data from columns
$2,$1,$3,$9 and in a new column sum $14 and $15. I want to then zip these files up when I am done. I want to return an appended table with all data from each of the above columns for downstream analysis. This is what I have and am having trouble with the zipping/unzipping part.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/ALSsummaryGWAS/Summary_Statistics_GWAS_2016/als.sumstats.meta.chr{1..22}.txt.gz
for f in $FILES;
do
  echo "$FILES"
  echo "extracting columns 2,1,3,9"
  awk '{print $2,$1,$3,$9, $14+$15}' > ALSGWAS.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in $FILES; do
  gzip -d < $f | awk '{print $2,$1,$3,$9, $14+$15}' | tee -a all.txt | gzip > $f.sub
done
```

Comment: Could also do `zcat "$f"` instead of `gzip -d`.